# Add a value into the 4th character of every row

Tags: sql, ms-access, format, sql-update

I'm not good with English but hope I can make my question clear.
I have a table with tons of rows, all written in the format 00000 (ex.: 000001, 00002 etc). I need to change all of them by adding a letter in a fixed point of the number (00A000, 00A001 etc), always the same letter, always in the same position. So, either i manage to change the format of the rows to a custom format number-number-letter-number-number-number (which i'm able to do in Excel, but i can't find a way in Access), or I create an update query to add the letter A in that spot. Anyone can help?

I tired to change the format as i said, but can't find a way to add custom format in access. I've tried to use an update query to add the letter after the 3rd character from the RIGHT, but i'ìve written the query wrong

Comment: What DBMS are you currently using?

Comment: I'm building this on access

Comment: Welcome alberto! The person who asked a question can mark one answer as "accepted". Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

You show one value with 6 digits and other with 5 digits. If that is correct, consider (x represents your field or string): `Left(x,2) & "A" & Mid(x,3)`

If that is a posting error and all values are same length of 5 digits, consider: `Format(x, "00A000")`.

Could run an UPDATE action to change data in field but it is not necessary as this calculation can be done when needed in query or textbox.

Could change field to a number type instead of storing repetitious characters. Also, Format property could use: `00\A000`.

Comment: worked like wonders, thank you man!